# Expression.Convert seems to by-pass MethodInfo (the third argument)?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I don't understand why it behaves so. Expression is something fairly new to me especially when using in LinqToEntity. Here is my code:

```
var getInt = GetType().GetMethod("getAnInt", BindingFlags.Static | 
                                             BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student));            
var id = Expression.Property(p, "ID");      
var eq = Expression.Equal(Expression.Convert(id, typeof(int), getInt), 
                          Expression.Constant(2));
var pred = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, bool>>(eq, p);
//use the pred in query
foreach(var student in myContext.Students.Where(pred)){
    //this always print ID 2 (which equals to the constant above);
    //no matter what is returned by the getAnInt method
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(student.ID);
}
//the getAnInt method 
static int getAnInt(string dummy){
   return 100;
}
```

In fact I'm just experimenting (not an actual issue in job). The `ID` field in database table is varchar having format of integer (convertible to int). I'm trying to convert the id into int (but not using the int.Parse static method because I'm experimenting with another method) before comparing to an int constant.

At first my `getAnInt` returned `int.Parse(dummy)` and worked OK but then I tried changing it to make it return an arbitrary integer. The result is so surprising that no matter what integer it returns, the `id` seems to be converted to `int` OK (as if it was converted by `int.Parse`) and compared with `Expression.Constant(2)`, which always filters for the student having id of `2`.

I expected the converted value of id should be the return value of `getAnInt` but it seems to be by-passed. I've also tried making another snippet of code to test the `Expression.Convert` and this shows that it works OK:

```
var t = typeof(Form1).GetMethod("Test", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
var c = Expression.Convert(p, typeof(int), t);
var e = Expression.Equal(c, Expression.Constant(10));
var f = Expression.Lambda<Func<string,bool>>(e, p);
var k = f.Compile()("1"); //test the value of k to see if it works.
                          //the parameter will be by-passed
                          //the return value of Test is obtained 
                          //and compared against constant 10 as expected.

static int Test(string dummy){
   return 10; //this makes the k above return true;
              //any other value makes it return false;
              //It seems to work OK here.
}
```

The only difference here is the first code is tested in context of LinqToEntity while the second just tries executing the compiled expression directly. I'm sure my `Students` entities have all interested values of `id` for my test.

As you see it's just an entity set, simple enough. I don't know how to debug when it comes to Expression. The second test was what I've tried to confirm if I understand `Expression.Convert` correctly.

Is there anything wrong in my first piece of code?

Comment: Anyway, i think LINQ to entites will NOT understand the call to a method like "GetAnInt". You should provide a direct value instead using Expression.Constant.

Comment: @GeorgeLica `getInt` is not a method, it becomes part of the `Expression.Convert`, I'm experimenting the `Expression.Convert`

Comment: @GeorgeLica I think in case it does not understand something, there should be some exception thrown, seriously it should behavior like that. At least I've tried the code with `int.Parse` static method first and it seems to work (convert string to int OK), but if I'd stopped there without experimenting more, I would have not encountered this problem.

Comment: The type of id in student is string or int?

Comment: @T.Rahgooy as I said it's a string (corresponding to varchar in database). However it's surely convertible to int (like as you can use int.Parse to convert it)

Comment: The conversion of the types in entity framework translates to sql commands, and it seems that entity framework ignores the conversion method and try to cast the types using the built in capabilities of sql. Log the generated sql, and check if the cast is done in sql command.

Comment: The only way you can use this method, is to commit the query(e.g. using ToList) and then apply the generated filter.

Comment: @T.Rahgooy looks like it cannot auto-translate the method body of my method to an expression (in other words Convert expression is just ***partially supported*** because it obviously accepts a `MethodInfo` to build up the expression but does not seem to work in almost cases). As I said I'm just experimenting especially the Convert expression. I've already known about filtering locally in which we use *LinqToObject* and freely do all things with Linq. Thanks for your comments anyway.